# Webpack Hot Reloader + ReactJS and Babel

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

Good evening,

I'm having a bit of trouble implementing the hot reloading feature of webpack. I'm practicing setting up my dev environment myself instead of taking someone else's boilerplate and not actually learning anything. In the terminal I can see that my output file `bundle.js` is being built on my express server, but there is a disconnect between that server and what is rendered in the client. I know this post is quite long but I want to provide the most information possible.

First my `webpack.config.js` file:

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
var path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  devtool: "source-map",
  entry: ["./src/main.js"],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "_build"),
    filename: "bundle.js",
    publicPath: "/static/"
  },
  plugins:[
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ],
  module:{
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: path.join(__dirname, "src/"),
        loader: "babel-loader"
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: path.join(__dirname, "src/stylesheets"),
        loaders: ["style", "css", "sass"]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

One of the issues I have with that file is that I'm under the impression my `entry` key should have an array as the value that looks like this: `["webpack-hot-middleware/src","./src/main.js"]`

But I get this error:

```
ERROR in multi webpack-hot-middleware/src ./src/main.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'webpack-hot-middleware/src' in '/Users/MMac/Freelance/slots'
```

I don't now why this is happening when all the other examples I'm working off of use this.

Second here is my `devServer.js`

```
var path = require("path");
var express = require("express");
var PORT = process.env.PORT || 7887;
var webpack = require("webpack");
var config = require("./webpack.config");
var app = express();
var compiler = webpack(config);

var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.use(require('webpack-dev-middleware')(compiler, {
  noInfo: true,
  publicPath: config.output.publicPath
}));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + "/_build")));

app.use(require('webpack-hot-middleware')(compiler));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(PORT, function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return;
  }
  console.log('Listening at ' + PORT);
});
```

Again this is set up 'correctly' according to the other examples I am working off of.

Lastly my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "slots",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack -d"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.21.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.16.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.3.0",
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.2",
    "react-router": "^3.0.1",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.7",
    "react-transform-hmr": "^1.0.4",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "sass-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.9.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.15.0"
  }
}
```

Thanks for looking over this post and I appreciate any helpful feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Here is just a shot in the dark (there are so many variables that can trip up Hot-Module-Replacement).

I think you are correct, the problem lies in your entry point. try this instead.

```
entry: [ "webpack-hot-middleware/client", "./src/main.js" ],
```

Also you need to add your babel presets to your config. Once you add the react-hmre it should work. See below for example.

```
module: {
 loaders: [
  {
   test: /\.js$/,
   loader: "babel",
   exclude: /node_modules/,
   query: { "presets": ["es2015","react", "react-hmre"] }
  }
 ]
},
```

If you have a .babelrc file you can also declare it here.

```
{
  "presets": ["react", "es2015"],
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "presets": ["react-hmre"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This took care of any errors. I've been working all morning trying to get this to work without success. At least now the code being sent from my devServer doesn't break. Basically what this saves me from having to do is rerun my webpack command to create my bundle.js file. Instead it is created every time I make a change, and then I have to refresh the browser. I really want to eliminate having to refresh the browser, though.

Comment: I would try removing  publicPath: "/static/" from your config all together and see if it auto-refreshes now.

Comment: Just updated my answer, this should solve your problem.

Comment: I made the suggested changes and I am still not experiencing any hot module replacement. I tried with and without the `/static/` public path and that didn't change anything. Could this be due to the fact that I am serving my files up through a node server? I can see that with every save a new `bundle.js` is being created in the terminal window where my server is running. Still the client is not being updated. I see this error with every save in the JavaScript terminal: `GET http://localhost:7887/__webpack_hmr net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING`